# .net core model binding type conversion errors

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling, model-binding

I have a .net core app. Some endpoint have some model and some property in the model have type int. If user pass string instead of int I have an error like this "Could not convert string to integer: asd. Path 'ClientId', line 3, position 22."
How to customize error message?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below codes to custom the error message.

You could add these codes into the ConfigureServices method.

```
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
                new BadRequestObjectResult("test");
        });
```

Result:

[image]

---

Update:

You could modify the error result according to your requirement.

```
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext 
            => {
                // Modify the codes according to the actionContext.ModelState's value 
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState); 
            
            };
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I also want to show to user what field is wrong.

Comment: You could modify the codes according to your requirement, you could get the model validate result by using `actionContext.ModelState`.